# PTIJ: How long do we have to give Biden?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It says famously in the opening Mishna of [Pirkei Avos](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.1?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi):

> הֱווּ מְתוּנִים בַּדִּין
>
> Be patient in the administration of [Biden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Biden)

And we can see from Rambam ([Mishneh Torah, Tzitzis 3:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Fringes.3.9?ven=The_Mishneh_Torah_by_Maimonides._trans._by_Moses_Hyamson,_1937-1949&vhe=Torat_Emet_370&lang=bi)) that he can go unchallenged even without seeing any relative success.

> אִם רָצוּ לַעֲשׂוֹת אוֹתָן בְּלֹא בְּרָכָה אֵין מְמַחִין בידן
>
> If they want to make him (President) and it is without any real blessing - we still don't protest about Biden.

So how long do we actually need to give the guy before voicing a negative opinion?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: See sefer Ezra.

Answer (score 2):

It says in [Brachot 54b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.54a.9?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "Rabbi Natan says another interpretation of the verse: “Make void Your Torah” because “it is the time to work for the Lord,” i.e., occasionally it is necessary to negate biblical precepts in order to bolster the Torah."

Therefore, if there is great urgency, we can go against the law of being patient with Biden and criticize him. So, if the urgency is immediate or almost immediate, we are allowed to criticize him.