# PTIJ: Biden and the towel

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Mishnah says [Shabbat 22:5]:

> אבל עשרה בני אדם מסתפגין באלונטית אחת פניהם ידיהם ורגליהם, ומביאין אותה בידן.

> However, ten people may use one towel to dry their faces, hands, and feet, and may carry it with Biden.

Why is the presence of Biden required for the ten to be allowed to do this?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128553/ptij-how-long-do-we-have-to-give-biden

Answer (score 8):

Because Biden needs to be extra dry, since if he's wet, there's a much higher chance of him slipping.

Comment: This made me laugh!! 

Comment: @shlomy -- You're absolutely right.  Since he's all wet all the time, he needs access to every towel he can get his hands on.